# argument error when using Ecto.Schema.has_many

Tags: elixir, ecto

when trying to setup a 1-to-n relationship between `User` and `Mandate`, the compiler throws an argument error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/platform/mandate.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:474: Ecto.Association.Has.get_ref/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:424: Ecto.Association.Has.struct/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/schema.ex:1679: Ecto.Schema.association/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/schema.ex:1474: Ecto.Schema.__has_many__/4
    lib/platform/mandate.ex:10: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

`mandate.ex` (excerpt):

```
defmodule Platform.Mandate do
  use Ecto.Schema

  @primary_key false
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :rules, :users, :id]}
  schema "mandates" do
    field(:id, Ecto.UUID, primary_key: true)
    field(:name, :string)

    has_many(:users, Platform.User, foreign_key: :mandate_id)

    embeds_many(:rules, __MODULE__.PermissionRule)

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

`user.ex` (excerpt):

```
defmodule Platform.User do
  @moduledoc false
  use Ecto.Schema
  use Coherence.Schema

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    belongs_to(:mandate, Platform.Mandate, references: :mandate_id)
    coherence_schema()

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

If I comment out the `has_many` call in `mandate.ex` it will compile, but then I obviously can't use preloads and associations.

### Environment

**Elixir** 1.4.2

**Erlang/OTP** 19

**Ecto** 2.1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that using `@primary_key false` is wrong when you want to use that key as a foreign key in another table.

As I want UUIDs for my keys, I had to use `@primary_key {:id, Ecto.UUID, autogenerate: true}` instead.